# Collapsible Toolbar with Custom View that Moves as Scrolling Happens and Gets Pinned (like in Phonograph)

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I would like to achieve something similar to the following in my app, but I want the whole red area (where it says "Guardians Of The Gala..." in the screenshots below) to be a custom view. (Some elements would fade out as the toolbar is collapsed.)

[image] ``
[image] ` 
[image]

I've been trying for hours and hours to get it to work, but to no avail.

Obviously, just putting it into `<Toolbar>` doesn't work, since it doesn't know that it's supposed to animate it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <ImageView/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
                <include layout="@layout/link_view_title_bar"/>
```

I've tried doing most of the answers from [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20collapsible%20toolbar%20custom%20view) and [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20collapsingtoolbarlayout%20subtitle) but nothing actually worked.

How could I do this, preferably using mostly XML and the Android Design Support library. Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: Can you explain the red thing and what it is exactly? Cannot understand what you want to implement.

Comment: @Keshav In the screenshots, the red area where it says "Guardians Of The Gala..."

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Keshav I want it to be a custom view/layout that will animate up when the user scrolls down, like in the screenshots. The standard `Toolbar`  (the one in my code) lets you only do `setTitle()` and `setSubtitle()`, not set a custom view, as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. There is a collapsing listener. You can try that.

Comment: @Keshav Thanks, but I'm not sure how that will work with the parallax scrolling (for the image in the background) and pinning the custom view to the top (and making it dissepear when scrolling down, and reappear when scrolling up), but I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100478/discussion-between-davidwroxy-and-keshav).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/homeCoordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeCollapseToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            //This can be changed to ImageView
            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/homeSliderLayout"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
                android:title=""
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="115dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            //Instead of the TabLayout, put your Red Layout
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/homeTabLayout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/homeViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try at soon as I get home.

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I like how it's an XML-only solution. Do you know how to make it so that the `Red Layout` does not overlap the image when the toolbar is fully expanded? (I know I can set the `paddingBottom` to be equal to the `Red Layout`'s height, but the `Red Layout`'s height is `wrap_content`, and setting this programmatically messes with the animation where the image is a shared element)

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. You mean to say that you dont want the red bar when it is scrolled down?

Comment: As seen in [this screenshot](https://goo.gl/UC4Wev), part of the image is behind the blue bar. Is there a way to make it not get cut off like this?

Comment: Right now the image size and the collapsingBarLayout size is same. Increase the size of collpasingBarLayout.

Comment: @davidwroxy Put your Red View out the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but keep it inside the `AppbarLayout`. It will work like charm